# Twitter Callback Issue Using Titanium OAuth Client for Android

Tags: callback, titanium, twitter-oauth, titanium-mobile

I'm using the following Titanium OAuth Client for a Share with Twitter feature in our Android app:

https://github.com/jeremyspouken/Titanium-OAuth-Client

The client works till the PIN Code screen. Then, if I have a callback URL defined in my Twitter App settings, it will redirect the user to that URL.. which I don't want. I read elsewhere that to disable the callback, to set oauth_callback=oob, which also is undesirable as it closes the Twitter screen after the PIN Code screen without having done anything.

Can someone help me understand what's the point of callback in Twitter oAUTH for mobile application, and how to make it work with my Titanium Andoid mobile app? I am about to pull my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect url can come in handy if you say want to promote your app or want the user who logs in to twitter via your app.
e.g for say angry birds, if you login to twitter then the redirect url can be say the angry birds twitter page.
you can prevent the closing of the web view by simply removing the call that destroys authorize UI from your oauth_adapter file.
not sure if this helps you. just let me know the comments if it does or not.